# SCRYPT [Need Help] Radeon 5970 HD [Apparently supposed to get 750-800KH/s) @ 300kh/s

Tags: scrypt

Okay, so I'm on Windows 7 and I'm only getting 300KH/s. Please help.

I'm using cgminer, I have the latest AMD drivers (Catalyst).

I'm using -T --intensity 18 -v 2 --worksize 256 --failover-only -d 0,1

GPU Specs:
730 MHz engine
1010 Memory

Also, I have to use -T in my batch file, otherwise I get a black screen.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez ? That made no sense ?

Comment: He was pointing out your spelling mistake.  It's "otherwise".

Comment: For what it's worth, the -T flag has no influence on mining speed.  It simply disables the fancy curses-based interface, which is purely for aesthetic purposes.

Answer (score 1):

There are many parameters to tweak in cgminer.  Its documentation explains precisely how to tune it, but for starters, you will probably just want to play with the intensity settings and perhaps more importantly, the --thread-concurrency flag.  Getting your thread concurrency right is crucial in getting a good mining speed.  You might start with a value of 8000.

Then you can play with more advanced flags, such as the ones that relate to overclocking.